# Inserting a string containing a SUMPRODUCT formula to Excel Table returns Run-Time Error 1004, how do i fix this?

Tags: excel, vba

### My Issue

I have a ~650 char string stored in the variable `formula` i would like to insert in an Excel Table. When running the code it returns  *Run-Time Error 1004 Application-defined or object defined error.* when trying to insert the high char string.

- My code works when inserting simple string like "=x".
- My code works when inserting a stringed formula like "=average(A2:B2)"
- My code also works when using `debug.print formula` (i.e the output is correct).
- My code also works when inserting a high char text only string e.g. "AAA.... x 650 times".

I am attempting to insert the whole string of a SUMPRODUCT formula with external workbook references in my table and suspect this being the issue. Again: the output from `debug.print formula` can be inserted directly in the cell and works. The Excel formula delimiter on my machine is a semicolon ";"

**Updated with code:**

```
  Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(('\\Path\[File - " & Name & ".xlsm]Position'!I$13:I$34=TEXT(" & Table1.DataBodyRange(i, 3).Address & ";""yyyy.mm.dd ""))*('\\Path\[File - " & Name & ".xlsm]Position'!$J$13:$J$34=" & Table1.DataBodyRange(i, 4).Address & ")*('\\Path\[File - " & Name & ".xlsm]Position'!$C$13:$C$34))-" & Table1.DataBodyRange(i, 5).Address

' Assume  Name = "Name"
```

**Debug.print output:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('\\Path\[File - Name.xlsm]Position'!I$13:I$34=TEXT(O3;"yyyy.mm.dd "))*('\\Path\[File - Name.xlsm]Position'!$J$13:$J$34=P3)*('\\Path\[File - Name.xlsm]Position'!$C$13:$C$34))-Q3
```

**How to i get Excel to ignore what it suspects to be a calculation error and insert the string anyway?**

Comment: Please include the full formula, you probably have a `"` to `""` issue.

Comment: would this not show in the debug.print if that was the case @ScottCraner? :-)

Comment: My guess would be that the formula string is not actually correct for the `Formula` property, which requires **US** locale entry - eg using commas to separate arguments.

Comment: @Rory is this still the case when i am able to paste the debug.print output directly to the cell?

Comment: Yes. If you would enter the formula with semicolons, the `Formula` property still requires commas.

Comment: Side note - use `.Formula` instead of `.Value` if you are inserting a formula.

Comment: If you would include the full formula we could help better.

Comment: I added it now, but you closed the question  @ScottCraner  :(

Comment: table1.DataBodyRange(i, 8).FormulaLocal= Formula did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: That is because it is a duplicate.

Comment: Agree. Have a good one

Comment: If you are going to share this outside you locale, I would recommend changing back to `.Formula` and making it EN_US standard, that way it is translated to the new host local settings properly.